# R - Criar coluna de controle a partir de outras duas colunas

Tags: r

Caros,

Tenho uma base de dados bem grande com a seguinte característica:

```
ORIENTAÇÃO   VOTO

Sim          Sim
Não          Sim
Sim          Não
Não          Não
```

Gostaria de criar uma terceira coluna na qual se os valores baterem, aparecerá 1. Se não bater, 0. Exemplo:

```
ORIENTAÇÃO   VOTO     CHECK

Sim          Sim        1
Não          Sim        0
Sim          Não        0
Não          Não        1
```

Podem me ajudar?
Muito obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou fazer em duas linhas de código.
Basta ver que os valores lógicos `FALSE/TRUE` são codificados internamente pelo R como inteiros `0/1`, respetivamente. Então, vê-se primeiro se os valores da duas colunas são iguais e depois transforma-se em inteiros.

Há ainda que ver se as colunas são de classe `"character"` ou `"factor"`. As funções `read.table` e derivadas assumem o argumento

```
stringsAsFactors = TRUE
```

e portanto, para não ter surpresas, as colunas são comparadas como `"character"`. Outra solução será ler os dados com o argumento acima com o valor `FALSE`.

```
dados$CHECK <- as.character(dados$ORIENTAÇÃO) == as.character(dados$VOTO)
dados$CHECK <- as.integer(dados$CHECK)

dados
#  ORIENTAÇÃO      VOTO CHECK
#1        Sim       Sim     1
#2        Não       Sim     0
#3        Sim       Não     0
#4        Não       Não     1
#5        Sim Abstenção     0
```

Outra opção é usar o pacote `dplyr`, muito popular para transformar dados.

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>% 
  mutate(ORIENTAÇÃO = as.character(ORIENTAÇÃO),
         VOTO = as.character(VOTO),
         CHECK = as.integer(ORIENTAÇÃO == VOTO))
```

O resultado é o mesmo.

## Edição.

Ainda outra solução.

```
dados$CHECK <- as.integer(Map(`==`, dados[[1]], dados[[2]]))
```

## Dados.

Acrescentei uma linha de dados para não ter os mesmos níveis do `"factor"` nas duas colunas, caso a base seja lida com o valor por defeito de `stringsAsFactors`. É esse o primeiro caso abaixo.

**1º caso:** Ler como `"factor"`.

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
ORIENTAÇÃO   VOTO
Sim          Sim
Não          Sim
Sim          Não
Não          Não
Sim          Abstenção
", header = TRUE)
```

**2º caso:** Ler como `"character"`.

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
ORIENTAÇÃO   VOTO
Sim          Sim
Não          Sim
Sim          Não
Não          Não
Sim          Abstenção
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Perfeito, Rui. Muitíssimo obrigado. Funcionou bem!
Forte abraço!